# Quantum observable measuring whether a particle is in a given spatial region

Tags: quantum-mechanics

What would an operator look like that measures the following thing? We have a particle in one dimension. A lamp goes on if the particle is found in a certain interval on the real axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator should have eigenvalue 1 (lamp on) if the particle is found within some interval $x\in [0,L]$, and eigenvalue 0 (lamp off) otherwise. Such an operator would look like
$$ P_{[0,L]} = \int_0^L\mathrm{d}x \; \lvert x\rangle \langle x \rvert, $$
i.e. it is a projector onto the subspace spanned by position eigenstates $\lvert x\rangle$ lying in the given interval. These position states are defined to be the eigenstates of the position operator $\hat{x}$ with eigenvalue $x$, i.e. $\hat{x}\lvert x\rangle = x\lvert x \rangle $, and they describe a particle that is perfectly localised at position $x$.

The eigenstates of the projection operator $P_{[0,L]}$ take the form
$$ \lvert \psi\rangle = \int_R\mathrm{d}x\; \psi(x) \lvert x\rangle,$$
where the integral extends over a region $R$ which is either completely contained *within* $[0,L]$, or completely *outside* $[0,L]$. The former corresponds to eigenvalue 1, the latter to eigenvalue 0. In other words, the eigenstates of $P_{[0,L]}$ have wave functions that vanish everwhere outside $[0,L]$ (eigenvalue 1) or everywhere inside $[0,L]$ (eigenvalue 0).

Comment: Thank you! And how would the $\lvert x\rangle$ look like? Isn't the only eigenstate the wave function itself then?

Comment: @Darius I have updated the answer. The eigenfunctions of the observable you are interested in must have support either completely inside or outside the interval, but are otherwise arbitrary. This makes sense: if the particle is definitely inside or outside the interval, it is in an eigenstate of the observable. In any other scenario it is not.

Comment: Thank you Mark! But is there than any special way the operator will look like (e.g. some matrix or something like that)? 
I fully understand what you wrote, but I somehow cannot really imagine how to build the operator out of the information I have now :/

Comment: @Darius It is difficult to give you advice without more detail on what problem you want to solve. In principle $P_{[0,L]}$ can only be represented by an infinite-dimensional matrix (i.e. it cannot be exactly represented by a matrix). However in practice I very much doubt you need to represent it as a matrix. If you merely want to calculate the probability of the lamp switching on given some state $\phi(x)$ of the particle, you only need the probability of finding the particle in the interval, i.e. $$ \langle \phi\rvert  P_{[0,L]}\lvert\phi\rangle=\int_0^L\mathrm{d}x\; \lvert\phi(x)\rvert^2.$$

Comment: And can't I build an operator out of the eigenstates by using something like a projection operator?

Comment: @Darius Yes, the spectral decomposition. The spectral decomposition of this operator is already given in the first equation of my post. I am sorry but if you want more help you need to give some more detail on what you want to calculate or understand. The operator has already been "built" for you in my answer. Any other representation will be equivalent to the equations that have already been given to you.

Comment: Well, first I just have to construct the operator, but there is no additional information. Further I have to compute the probability of finding the particle in a certain interval I, thats all I have :/

Comment: @Darius The operator is constructed in the first equation of the answer. The probability of finding the particle in an interval $[0,L]$ is given in one of my comments.

Comment: I think my confusion goes as I do not really get an answer with a number in this exercise. But I think that this is not possible here. Thank you very very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In general, the expectation value for any observable quantity is found by putting the quantum mechanical operator for that observable in the integral of the wavefunction over space: $$\langle Q\rangle= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*\hat{Q}\;\psi\; dV.$$

Comment: Thank you, I already knew that, but can this help me?

Comment: This is a mathjax-enabled site. It supports $\LaTeX$; do take advantage of it:)